# Static particles freak out after certain amount of time?

Tags: animation, particles, baking

Ok, I have been trying to maintain "static" particles, meaning they stay the same count and just vibrate in place (like atoms) - like this https://dribbble.com/shots/4936693-VR-Birds

I have achieved this by just having start and end frame be same -

[image]

My problem is clearly Im doing something wrong because maybe 5 seconds after the start/end frame, the particles freak out and move really fast away from the desired volume:

[image]

(where before they were in that box by the cursor)
How can I stop them from exploding? Is it something with the lifetime?

EDIT:
[image]

2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Additionally** (re-editing my last answer)
I am attaching a blend file in which I noticed that I had to use Brownian Force and Damp instead of Turbulence or any other kind of field.

[image]

This should do the work.

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ja7Qu1-UxJdJJqHs1ml9ZpSjgmOskB7s)

In order to keep the particles still you must turn off the Normal property in the Emiter Geometry under the tab Velocity of your Particles System.

[image]

The second thing that you have to do, so your particles will not go towards the "ground plane" is to turn off the Gravity affection in the "Field Weights" Tab.
From this panel you will also set the desired affection from other fields (such as Turbulence, Wind, Vortex etc) that you may use to give to your particles the kind of movement you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: I did that but still freaks out - I have Newtonian physics on, maybe thats it? But I need physics to keep them wiggling in place. See my edit

Comment: do you have a cache file ? if yes clear it first. You need Newtonian turned on for sure.

Comment: Right, I believe I cleared the cache I clicked "Free all Bakes (see edit) but still won't work

Comment: hm sounds really strange, what if you do it from scratch in a new file ? Can you reproduce the effect ?

Comment: yup, in that birds example I had it happen too but I just made a new emitter, but thats not sustainable

Comment: If you have it working would you maybe upload a blend file?

Comment: check the update and get the demo file